# Merging duplicated indicies within a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, ipython

I have a single dataframe, which after cleanup and merging has ended up in a state where I have multiple rows with the same index value.

I need to merge these duplicate rows and get out a dataframe which has a single row for each run of duplicates.

This feels like it should be a standard operation when working with dataframes, but I can't seem to work out how to make Pandas do it.

The best answer I have found is here: [Merge two rows in the same Dataframe if their index is the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411583/merge-two-rows-in-the-same-dataframe-if-their-index-is-the-same)

However the solution posited there ends me with a "groupby" object rather than a dataframe. Since I want to then do a further groupby on the frame, I have no idea how to proceed.

Is there a standard function in method in pandas for compacting a dataframe where multiple rows share the same index, that returns a new dataframe?

ex:

```
           visits  revenue product-type
product1      200       50    stockings
product1       50      100         #n/a
product2      150       20          toy
     ...       ..       ..           ..
```

to

```
           visits  revenue product-type
product1      250      150    stockings
product2      150       20          toy
     ...       ..       ..           ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` and then [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
print (df.groupby(level=0).agg({'visits':sum,'revenue':sum,'product-type':'first'}))

          visits  revenue product-type
product1     250      150    stockings
product2     150       20          toy
```

Maybe better function for last column is `join` - your data are not lost, ([`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) takes only first value, other data are removed):

```
print (df.groupby(level=0).agg({'visits':sum,
                               'revenue':sum,
                               'product-type': lambda x: ''.join(x.fillna(''))}))

          visits  revenue product-type
product1     250      150    stockings
product2     150       20          toy
```

If use only `sum`, last column is removed - [automatic exclusion of nuisance columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns):

```
print (df.groupby(level=0).sum())
          visits  revenue
product1     250      150
product2     150       20
```